# Test taking photos via adb monkey

Tags: android

My App takes photos using the the system Intent

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(
   android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageFileUri );
...
```

I'd like to test my App using the test Monkey; but so far I haven't been able to get the Monkey to take pictures. Is this possible?

The following is the best I've been able to come up with:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.google.android.camera -p ny.package.name -v 500
```

When I run this command, my App is launched and the camera Activity is also launched correctly. It even seems like the Monkey taps on the take picture button within the system camera App. From watching the Monkey run, it would seem like a possible explanation could be that the Monkey taps on other buttons before the image can actually be saved, and for some reason this 'cancels' the Save photo action.

BTW, I'm running the Monkey on a Nexus one with Android 2.3.6, not an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tool, **monkey** is an [UI/Application Exersiser](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) that generates pseudo-random streams of user events such as clicks, touches, or gestures, as well as a number of system-level events. You can use the Monkey to stress-test applications that you are developing, in a random yet repeatable manner.

Most probably, what you are looking for if your intention is to test a single event is [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html), a tool that provides an API for writing programs that control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code. In such way you will be able to connect to the device and send the event that triggers the image capture.

Comment: Yes, monkeyrunner is a good alternative, but I don't see why the adb monkey is **wrong** for testing my App. I think both approaches are complementary, and that's why there are two tools.